# What does "read -p" do in a linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script that I have copied and edited. There are a couple of lines in there that I need explaining if possible please.

These are the lines:

```
     read -p "please enter the username you wish to create: " username
     if id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

What does `read -p` do? What does `id -u` do? What does `>/dev/null 2&1;` do?
Then further on in the script, it has this line that says this:

```
     sudo useradd -g $group -s $bash -d $homedir -m $username -p $password
```

Again please could someone explain all the minus signs in this line please? (`-g`, `-s`, `-d`, `-m`, `-p`)

Comment: `read -p` doesn't exist in shell programming. It exists in `bash` and other higher level shells. The `-p` "stuff that follows" means `prompt` with what follows.

Comment: Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook is a good place to start

Comment: You should ask that either on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KevinDTimm the man page for read doesn't appear to mention -p or prompt anywhere (at least for me). Try `man read | grep -e "-p" -e "prompt"`.

Comment: @MauveRanger - read the comment after mine

Comment: @KevinDTimm - Hmm. You're right: I'm getting the wrong man page, read(2), which is some utility for reading files. `read` is also prompt for input, yet `man -a read` only presents the one page. And there's clearly a page for it somewhere: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html I think the problem is on my end.

Comment: See here: https://ss64.com/bash/read.html. For `read` help, also see `read -h` for a short help context and `help read` for a long one.

Answer (score 20):

First off, the structure `<command> -<option>` means that you want to execute `<command>` using the *option* corresponding to `<option>`. A `-` after a command means that the following letter is an option. Most commands have several options you can use. Options are usually defined using either a single letter or a couple of words separated by `-`.

*Side Note*: For options that are a couple of words rather than a single letter, often it will use two minus signs `--` instead of one, signifying that it is a "long named" option.

So, using the `read -p` example, this means you want to execute `read` using the `p` option, which stands for *prompt*.

Now, sometimes an option will require an argument. In your examples, the options to `useradd` have arguments. Arguments are usually defined like `<command> -<option> [argument]`. So, in the `useradd` example, `$group` is an argument for the option `g`.

---

Now for the commands themselves:

[`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) is a bash built-in (not a POSIX shell command) that reads from standard input.

- The `-p` option makes it read as a prompt, meaning it doesn't add a trailing newline before trying to read input.

[`if`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) checks the return status of the test command (in this case `id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1`)

- If the return status is 0, the `then` part is executed

[`id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/id) prints user groups and ids

- The `-u` option "prints only the effective user ID".
- [`>/dev/null 2>&1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119648/redirecting-to-dev-null) redirects standard input and standard error to `/dev/null`, meaning they do not get printed to the terminal.

[`useradd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) creates a new user

- `-g` sets the initial group for the user
- `-s` sets the name of the user's login shell
- `-d` sets the name of the user's login directory
- `-m` says to create the user's home directory if it does not exist.
- `-p` defines the user's encrypted password.

For future reference, you can look up commands in the linux manual pages by doing `man <command>` on the command line. These manual pages tell you what a command does, as well as explaining all of its options.

Bash built-ins like `read` are all on a single man page that is not the easiest thing to use. For those I find googling them easier. Usually http://ss64.com/ will come up in the results, which contains the info from the bash built-ins man page, but separated into different pages by command. I find this much easier to use.

Comment: Note `read -p` is not part of the POSIX shell. It is a bash/other high level shell addition. Your answer is correct for those, but it is worth pointing out, in light of the way this question is tagged. It may also be worth pointing out that `-` signifies the next letter that follows corresponds to an *option*.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful ss64.com tip!